# how to call a parameterized method from the developer console?

Tags: apex

I wrote this code on apex class

```
public class greeting{
    String Hi = 'Good Morning Mike';
    Integer num1 = 34;
    Integer num2 = 43;
    public  void printHi()  {
        System.debug(Hi);
    }
    public static Integer add(Integer num1, Integer num2){
        Integer sum = num1 + num2;
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Now on the developer console I want to call the method add() to get the sum of 2 numbers
I called the class and the other method printHi() correctly but I could not call the add method.

```
greeting first = new greeting();
first.printHi();
first.add();
```

How should I do it without an error?

Answer (score 0):

'add' method in above class expects two parameters to be passed when being called.

If you call 'first.add()' without passing any parameter code will try to find a function with name as 'add' which doesn't expect any parameter. Moreover here our method is static which can't be called via instance.

You need to execute below to run your snippet in dev console

```
Integer sum = greeting.add(1,4); // here 1 and 4 are your arguments and we are taking return value in sum variable
```

Considering your method is static we don't need to create a instance of class rather it can be called directly using class name

Note : As good practice you should following naming conventions. For example
Class name should be noun and written in PascalCase.
Variable name should be more descriptive

Comment: Thanks a lot . I removed the static part and tried to execute like first.add(1,4); . now on developer console no error but returns no value?

Comment: Did you take output in some variable like Integer sum = first.add(1,4) and try printing sum variable and request you to update question with new code you tried

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not write System.debug(first.add(1,4)); and I think because of that I cannot see any output on developer console.Now I wrote it and saw the output.I appreciate your help

Comment: Please accept the answer in case it helped

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer helped me

Comment: No problem, although I meant accept the answer for your question and upvote so it can help other people with same query in future as well.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your `add()` method as `static`, which means that you call it using the name of the class instead of an instance of the class.

Other than that, you just need to pass the correct number and type of arguments like you would with any other method.

wrong
`first.add(1, 2);`

correct
`Greeting.add(1,2);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I removed static and then on developer console I called the method first.add(1,2);  now no error but returns no value

Comment: @AdamWallace `system.debug(first.add(1,2));` will show the result; simply doing `first.add(1,2)` without a place to hold/display the result will not show anything at certain debug levels